# Acts as paranoid is not recovering associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-paranoid

I am attempting to use the [acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) gem with no luck.  I have a `Client` model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_paranoid
    has_many :purchases, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :payments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and when I destroy a client with purchases and / or payments, and then attempt to recover, only the client is recovered, and not the associations.

```
> c = Client.find(231)
> c.payments.length
  Payment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 231]]
 => 1
> c.purchases.length
  Purchase Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "purchases".* FROM "purchases" WHERE "purchases"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 231]]
 => 1
```

If I delete the client:

```
> c.destroy
```

and run `Client.only_deleted`, I see the client that was just deleted.  However, when I recover it and attempt to load the purchases or payments, there are none.

```
> Client.only_deleted.first.recover
> c = Client.find(231) # success
> c.payments.length # fail
  => 0
```

The associated records are not recovered.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realize I needed to run:

```
bin/rails generate migration AddDeletedAtToControllerName deleted_at:datetime:index
```

for all the associated models and add:

```
acts_as_paranoid
```

to the model's as well.  After adding that, everything runs as expected

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is because `acts_as_paranoid` overwrites the `destroy` method for a ruby class. That means that associations with `dependent: :destroy` will act the same as they would if `acts_as_paranoid` wasn't defined on the class and would actually delete associated records.

So for every associated and dependent record that you want to prevent from being permanently deleted, yes, you will need to ensure that those records have `acts_as_paranoid` functionality as well.

Comment: Isn't this the same as what I wrote below?

Comment: It is! I just wanted to clarify the reason this is happening is because of the destroy callbacks.

You might want to edit your response below to `AddDeletedAtToControllerName` to be `AddDeletedAtToModelName` though since that makes more sense to add a migration for a model instead of a controller.

Answer (score 0):

for all the associated models and add: **act_as_paranoid**

```
 class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_paranoid
 end
 
 class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_paranoid
 end
```

In this case
`c = Client.find(231)`,
`c.destroy`

It will works fine on deleting case, but when you recover that record then nothing will recover from associated as well.
if you will remove **dependent: :destroy** from model where you want soft deletion using **act_as_paranoid**.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :payments
end
```

this will works for you.
Because destroy method for a ruby class. That means associations with dependent: :destroy will act the same as they would if acts_as_paranoid wasn't defined on the class and would actually delete associated records.